# Automatically Reply on email address

Tags: email, exchange

I manage my own email domain using Microsoft Exchange Online. I've configured the Mail Flow on the server so that any text before the `@` on an email (for a specific subdomain), automatically routes to my own mailbox. It also adds information to the header to indicate that it has been routed.

[image: Mail Flow Configuration]

These email addresses do not actually exist in exchange, it's just configured to accept them and send them to my mailbox. If I reply to these emails, the reply comes from my *actual* email address.

I'd like to configure my exchange so that if I were to reply to these emails, they would get automatically re-marked as coming from the same email as the incoming address. Is this possible?

i.e. If I receive an email on `Whatever@subdomain.mydomain.com`, I want the reply address to be `Whatever@subdomain.mydomain.com`, rather than `MyName@mydomain.com`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such a mail flow rule to realize this.
As a workaround, you could create that mailbox in Exchange. Assign your mailbox “Send As” permission to this account. Just like they mentioned in [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/8049813f-d77c-45b4-be53-907e488f0314/allowing-an-ad-service-account-to-send-smtp-as-any-from-address?forum=exchange2010).

When sending from Outlook client, just click “From” > “Other Email Address”. The record will remain there. Next time, you can easily choose that address in “From” drop-down menu.
[image]

Another option is described in this blog: [How to add an alias to an Office 365 account and how to set up Outlook to send email messages as this alias](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hot/2012/04/26/how-to-add-an-alias-to-an-office-365-account-and-how-to-set-up-outlook-to-send-email-messages-as-this-alias/)